# scope access in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having trouble accessing a variable using angularjs and ionic. I have a page where I am listing an amount of items:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
              item="item"
              href=""
              style="max-height:70px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"
              >             

             <div class="containerText" style="position:absolute; float:left; margin-left:60px">
                <div class="" style="font-size:11px">               
                    {{item.datea}}
                </div>
                <div class="" style="margin-top:4px; font-weight:bold; text-align:right">
                    {{item.value}}                  
                </div>
            </div>
(...)
```

And I want to load the item.value when I press the "download" button that each item row has next to the delete icon:

[image: screenshot of the app]

I am converting all the numbers to strings in the input field to make it easier to control the changes (like adding a decimal point or deleting the last value of that string).

My controller.js has these functions:

```
$scope.searchText = "0";
```

(...)

```
/****************** KEYBOARD FUNCTIONS ************************/    
//Adds a number in the field text above the keyboard
$scope.addNumber = function(num) {

 //limiting the amount of numbers in the display 
 if (this.searchText.length < 20)
     if (this.searchText == "0")
         if (num != '.')
             this.searchText=num;
         else
             this.searchText = (this.searchText) + num;
     else
         if (num!='.')
             this.searchText = (this.searchText) + num;
         else if (this.searchText.indexOf('.') == -1)
             this.searchText = (this.searchText) + num;             
}

//Used to delete the number in the screen and set it to 0  
//AKA RESET
$scope.deleteNumbers = function(){ 
  this.searchText= "0"; 
  console.log("ERASING!");
}

//Used to delete the last entered digit/symbol
$scope.deleteLast = function(){
     this.searchText = this.searchText.slice(0, -1);
     if (this.searchText.length==0)
     {
        this.searchText = "0";
     }  
}  

//used to load the values of an element of the list to the display
$scope.loadItem = function(valueToAdd){

    console.log("Load values ");

    $scope.deleteNumbers();
    $tempVal = valueToAdd.toString();   
    $scope.addNumber($tempVal);

    console.log("value in this.searchText " + this.searchText);
    console.log("value in scope.searchText " + $scope.searchText);
    console.log(isNaN($tempVal));
}
```

And it loads nicely the first execution (only if I have not pressed the coded keyboard before), but after touching my created keyboard, the "load number" function stops working.

My console.log looks like this when I load the page and I press one of thos download buttons:

```
controllers.js:185 Load values 
controllers.js:77 ERASING!
controllers.js:212 value in this.searchText 14458.553
controllers.js:213 value in scope.searchText 14458.553
controllers.js:214 false
```

As you can see, it says that it is a numeric value that has been loaded into the field, but it let's me add additional numbers or delete the chars of the input string without problem, but if I want to load another value (or even the same previously loaded) it seems that the scope gets messed up as I get this output.

```
controllers.js:185 Load values 
controllers.js:77 ERASING!
controllers.js:212 value in this.searchText 14458.55
controllers.js:213 value in scope.searchText 15429.477
controllers.js:214 false
```

I have tried modifying at the same time this.searchText and scope.searchText but without result. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: can you avoid using this.searchText altogether and use only $scope.searchText?

Comment: also, giving your variable the name $templVal is bad practice. try to avoid prefixing your variable names with $. jquery and angular really love this prefix and this will both confuse you and might lead to breaking infrastructure code (such as a collision with internal implementation of jquery and or angularjs)

Comment: finally, addNumber looks like a function that is expecting a single digit, while your $tempVal potentially holds multiple digits. I'm not sure addNumber always works correctly in this use case

Comment: Hi Uri, actually replacing this.searchText to $scope.searchText fixes the issue. Thank you so much! addNumber seems to work fine even though what you say is true. Would you recommend making an additional function for loading the saved numbers?

Comment: I can see now why it does work, but it was confusing initially. For clarity reasons only I would suggest changing your code slightly. I think that another function isn't necessary. You can do: "$scope.searchText = valueToAdd.toString()"